# We are unable to change your subscription plan. Manage subscriptions in android application

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-subscriptionmanager

Im using in-app subscription in my application. there are 3 subscription available  in application i.e, monthly, 6 month and yearly. If user subscribed with monthly I'm showing upgrade subscription on some point. If user try to upgrade its upgrading but after it show pop-up (We are unable to change your subscription plan. Manage subscriptions).But I'm able to get new token and subscription info from the interface(onPurchasesUpdated). Here is the code below using for upgrade.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBDiG.jpg)

```
billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build()
            ) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
                try {
                    if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty() && skuDetailsList.size > 0) {
                        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(token)
                                        .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION).build())
                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0])
                                .build()
                        val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), billingFlowParams)
                    } else {
                        CommonUtil.toastShow(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.something_went_wrong))
                    }
                } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                    CommonUtil.toastShow(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.something_went_wrong))
                }
```